# How to hide a Widget when the program starts in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have some objects in a PyQt GUI that I wish to be hidden when the program runs until a button is pressed that shows them. So far all my attempts have failed, I have experimented with Signals/Slots but I can't seem to find a way of calling a function without an action (e.g. a button press). I would like to know if it is possible to call hide() on an object in this way, and if so, how.

Comment: Why the downvote, should I edit my question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Close:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.closeWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("activated()")), widgetName.close)
```

To Show:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionShow, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("activated()")), widgetName.show)
```

In other words, widgets inherit a close() and show() method.

See http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html

Also, some example code:  http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/06/more-pyqt-example-code/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the signal "activated()" doesn't seem to work for me (did you put it as an example for a signal?), is there a signal emitted when the program starts that I could use?

Comment: Those signals are from button clicks.  Have you tried simply:

widgetName.close()?  Look at the example in the second link.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but I get NameError: global name 'favouritesRadio' is not defined, I think because I am putting that line in the wrong place in my .py file. "favouritesRadio" definitely exists, I can do other things with it.

Comment: Is it OK if I edit it for brevity, it's about 300 lines?

Comment: Go for it - unless you think its necessary - then use pastebin.

Comment: Edit your original post.

Comment: What do you want me to change about my original post?

Comment: Ah fixed it, I forgot to put "self." in front of it. Thanks for your help!